# Advanced search tips: how to filter on negative scored questions?

Tags: support, search

I can search questions on meta with a score better than 20 like this:

[`is:question score:20`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+score%3A20)

I can search questions with score between 20 and 30 like this:

[`is:question score:20-30`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+score%3A20-30)

How can I search questions on meta with a score worse than -20?

How can I search questions on meta with a score between -20 and -30?

**Could this info please be added to the "Advanced search tips" section?**

[image: tip]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I search questions on meta with a score worse than -20?

[`is:question score:..-20`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+score%3A..-20)

> How can I search questions on meta with a score between -20 and -30?

[`is:question score:-30..-20`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+score%3A-30..-20)

See: [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) There is a *Range Operators* section among the *Advanced Search Options*. I just exchanged the example figures by negative ones.

I guess, the list of *Advanced Search Tips* is not meant to be exhaustive. This is why the above help page is linked at the end of that list.

Comment: Just a quick note here, the smaller number has to be first in the range (-30 in this case).